# AVAudioRecorder How to gain mic level in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am develop audio recording app for iphone 6+.
problem 1: (AVAudioRecorder)audio recording work fine in simulator but not work in device..

Audio Settings:

```
[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0f] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];

[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:AVAudioQualityLow] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
```

problem 2: before mic working well in my ipad. but when i use this code

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
 [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
```

mic not work in ipad.. how to reset or gain my mic level in ipad/iphone

Comment: I am having the exact same issues. Will be sure to post an answer when I work it out.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: yeah thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `- (void)setUpAudio` method I have created a dictionary which holds the settings for the AVAudioRecorder.(It's a bit cleaner) Your code above is almost correct, but not quite. See below.

```
// empty URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

// define settings for AVAudioRecorder
NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                      AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless],      AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],                               AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMax],               AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

// init and apply settings
 recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

// This here is what you are missing, without it the mic input will work in the simulator, 
// but not on a device.
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                    error:nil];

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    NSTimer *levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [recorder record];
} else {
    NSLog([error description]);
}
```

Then in the update method you can keep track of your mic input levels like this.

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];
    NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input: %f", [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);

}
```

Any questions or ways I can improve my answer please let me know. Still pretty new around here.